# python 3.4.2 urlib no attribute 'pathname2url'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Why is the next code not working? I cant find why.

```
import mimetypes
import glob, urllib

for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH"):
    url = urllib.pathname2url(file)
    print(file, mimetypes.guess_type(url))
```

The error message I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pathname2url'
```

I am trying display all file typs of a directory. Is this a good way? Or is there a better way. I dont want to use the module magic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This function's location has changed in Python 3. It is now [`urllib.request.pathname2url`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.pathname2url).

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping me. Maby a stupid question but I replaced  'url = urllib.pathname2url(file)' to: url = urllib.request.pathname2url(file) But It stil display a error message. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request']

Comment: @joey you need to either `import urllib.request`, in which case the code in your comment will work as-is, or do something like `from urllib.request import pathname2url`, in which case you should change your code to `url = pathname2url(file)`. Also, while using `file` as a variable name is technically OK, [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a built-in function in Python 2, so if you'll ever be working in that version of the language you'll have to be careful about masking it.