# In robot framework, python library urllib3 module doesn't have attribute pathname2url

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I tried to upgrade a few packages with pip and also my python from 3.9 to 3.9.**13**. so now i use RIDE v2.0b1 running on Python 3.9.13. i use robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1.**4**. instead of 1.1 and urllib3 1.26.**12** instead of 1.26.9 for calls to webservices
I get an error when running a keyword of sudslibrary (Create Soap Client)

**FAIL : AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'pathname2url'**

Since i don't have any knowledge of python and all solutions on google are about python, i'm stuck with this error. could anybody please help me?
In [python 3.4.2 urlib no attribute 'pathname2url'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654772/python-3-4-2-urlib-no-attribute-pathname2url) it says that pathname2url function of urllib is now in another library which is urllib.**request**.pathname2url.

Should i install this python library independently by pip?
it's strange because with my older installations (ython 3.9) i didn't have urllib.**request**.pathname2url library when i pip(ed) list it.
Thank you for your precious help i'm badly stucked

Comment: What Python version were you using before? What exact code are you running that's causing this error? Looks like something very similar was posted in [this GitHub issue on their repo](https://github.com/ombre42/robotframework-sudslibrary/issues/34). Unfortunately it doesn't have any responses, but looks like you're trying to upgrade from Python 2 to 3.

Comment: i was using python 3.9 before with robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1 and urllib3 1.26.9 and calling webservices keywoards like Create Soap Client  abc.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

This seems a problem on the sudslibrary you are using. A possible workaround is to fix the offending code by replacing with the new module reference.

You could (should?) find all references to the import or use of `pathname2url`in that module library and replace with fixing code. For example:

```py
import urllib.request.pathname2url as pathname2url
```

or
if you have `from urllib import pathname2url`

```py
from urllib.request import pathname2url
```

The best would be, after identifying the fix, to propose a Pull Request for the sudslibrary, with something like:

```
try:
   from urllib import pathname2url
except ImportError:
   from urllib.request import pathname2url
```

And similar for the absolut imports.

Comment: Thank you Helio. I'm not a developer.So, very basic questions:

Comment: Thank you, Helio, I'm not a developer so my understanding is 1-I go to the source code of robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1.4. (which is not on my PC but on pypi, i download it) 2-I search inside all files of this library, all the occurences of pathname2url  3-if it's written like urllib.pathname2url, instead of changing it to urllib.request.pathname2url, i either add at top of the file where pathname2url was used,  import urllib.request.pathname2url as pathname2url     or       from urllib.request import pathname2url   Now i should compile this python source code, and

Comment: and somewhere ? i use try:
   from urllib import pathname2url
except ImportError:
   from urllib.request import pathname2url

Comment: No, the files are installed on your system. Usually in `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra` (if on windows, and not sure about the module name). You can edit them directly.
Or, you can use the downloaded source, modify the files, and then install (`pip install -U .` if you are in the root of the source code.

Comment: Thank you i found sudslibrary  and the only file and only line that call pathname2url function. but it uses the correct class(module)

Comment: Thank you i found sudslibrary  and the only file and only line which calls pathname2url function is the following which is inside a DEF in a Class:                                                                                    url_or_path = 'file:' + urllib.request.pathname2url(url_or_path)                                         strangely it uses the correct urllib.request class.At top of this python file, i have:            import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error    should i modify it to:                   
 import urllib.request.pathname2url as pathname2url  ?  thank you

Comment: No need for change if that code is correct, then it is not where your original error comes from: `FAIL : AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'pathname2url'`. Are you sure that was the library which caused the error?

Comment: my RFcode fails when i call Create Soap Client. this keyword is inside robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1.4 which seems to be a wrapper of the python lib of sudslibrary.inside one of sudslibrary file i have this "create Soap client" method which uses pathname2url. so my error seems to me correlated

Comment: So that is the library to fix, not the original sudslibrary as you say it is correct.

Comment: Since my python comptency was very limited, i tried to circumvent the path2url function by constructing my absolute path to my wsdl file in this way:                             ${myAbsProjectDir_Win_Lin}=    Set Variable    ${CURDIR}${/}..${/}..${/}..${/} ${myAbsDir_URLFormat}=    Replace String    ${myAbsProjectDir_Win_Lin}    ${/}    /  ${Chemin_Fichier_WSDL}=    Set Variable    file:\/\/\/${myAbsDir_URLFormat}       Ceate Soap Client   ${Chemin_Fichier_WSDL}.a.wsdl